# AstroJS Image crashes dev server

Tags: image, import, crash, astrojs

I try to get an image into my prjoject via Astro/Image. The "normal"  works fine but not with the component of .

I did the import :

```
import { Image, Picture } from "@astrojs/image/components";

...
  <Image src={import('../src/images/neu/about.jpg')} width={300} alt="test"/>
```

I did the astro.config.mjs:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

// https://astro.build/config
import image from "@astrojs/image";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  site: 'https://juni-test.de',
  integrations: [image()]
});
```

and I get this Error while dev-server shuts down:

```
PS C:\Users\rober\Projekte\JuniKaefer> npm run dev

> @example/basics@0.0.1 dev
> astro dev

   astro  v1.9.2 started in 205ms

  ┃ Local    http://localhost:3000/
  ┃ Network  use --host to expose

node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "fetch failed".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

So I think there is a problem to fetch the Image but the Image exists. No idea what to do.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Astro 1.9.2 does not support Node 18, you either have to downgrade your Node version or upgrade Astro to the new 2.0 beta using the command `npm i astro@beta`  (Astro 2.0 officially releases in 5 days on 01/24/23)

also I think the import path is invalid, assuming your on the index page `src/pages/index.astro` and your images are located in `src/images`, the import path should be

```
import('../images/neu/about.jpg')
```